# How accurate is "everything is a file" in regards to linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Suppose I were to set up an ubuntu machine and install some services and software on it. Further suppose I were to set up another stock ubuntu machine, this time without the additional services and software. I know there are ways of creating installation/setup scripts or taking disk images and such to build large numbers of identical machines, but if I were to programmatically take a file-based diff between the installations and migrate all file additions/changes/removals/etc from the fully configured system to the stock system, would I then have two identical, working systems (i.e. a full realization of the 'everything is a file' linux philosophy), or would the newly configured system be left in an inconsistent state because simply transferring files isn't enough? I am excluding hostname references and such in my definitions of identical and inconsistent.

I ask this because I need to create a virtual machine, install a bunch of software, and add a bunch of content to tools like redmine, and in the near future I'm going to have to mirror that onto another vm. I cannot simply take a disk image because the source I receive the second vm from does not give me that sort of access and the vm will have different specs. I also cannot go with an installation script based approach at this point because that will require a lot of overhead, will not account for the added user content, and I won't know everything that is going to be needed on the first vm until it our environment is stable. The approach I asked about above seems to be a roundabout but reasonable way to get things done so long as it its assumptions are theoretically accurate.

Thanks.

Comment: If someone is going to rate this down, at least post an explanation.

Comment: One thing to note is that Ubuntu and in fact many modern/current distros will use device identifiers for mount-points. In the physical world they'd be tied to the hardware, in other words a physical clone of /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/menu.lst won't just work on the new machine, it will not boot.  How VMs behave in this respect I do not know.

Comment: How is this a programming question?  You'd get the same result as if you used someone's existing diff tool.

Comment: This is validation of assumptions that programming/scripting would be based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the two systems are largely identical in terms of hardware (that is, same network cards, video cards, etc), simply copying the files from system A to system V is generally entirely sufficient.  In fact, at my workplace we have used exactly this process as a "poor man's P2V" mechanism in a number of successful cases.

If the two systems have different hardware configurations, you may need to make appropriate adjustments on the target system to take this into account.

### UUID Mounts

If you have UUID based mounts -- e.g., your `/etc/fstab` looks like this...

```
UUID=03b4f2f3-aa5a-4e16-9f1c-57820c2d7a72 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

...then you will probably need to adjust those identifiers.  A good solution is to use label based mounts instead (and set up the appropriate labels, of course).

### Network cards

Some distributions record the MAC address of your network card as part of the network configuration and will refuse to configure your NIC if the MAC address is different.  Under RHEL-derivatives, simply removing the MAC address from the configuration will take care of this.  I don't *think* this will be an issue under Ubuntu.